# How To Draw Component With POJO As Model In UML?

Tags: servlets, components, ejb, uml, pojo

i've build an web application, i have servlet as controler and java classes as the request handdler

so if the servlet receive an request from a client, it will call method from the request handler to process the request, and then the request handler will have to call an ejb to do the business logic, and when the ejb has done it process, the request handler will give the client an response(JSP Page)

so the question is, how to draw the UML based the stucture i've describe above? how to describe relationship between an component(servlet and ejb) with the pojo(requesthandler)?thx for help

---

is it right to draw like this?

http://i56.tinypic.com/2lmx6c5.jpg

thx

Comment: do you want to draw the static relationships or behaviour flow?  Class Diagram for former, sequence/activity diagram for latter.

Comment: so i dont need to draw component diagram?can i add a class diagram to component diagram?

Comment: you don't *need* to draw anything.  Question is what's the reason for drawing anything?  i.e. what information do you want to convey with your diagram(s)?  UML provides various different diagrams, each showing different aspects of your system.  The diagram(s) you choose will depend on what you want to communicate with it.

Comment: for formal documentation in my thesis, i want to show how my program works, how it takes care the process/request, what it do to fulfill the request.

Comment: ok.  "How it works" suggests you want to use either sequence diagram or activity diagram.  It should be pretty easy to draw a sequence diagram that directly represents para. 2 in your question.  A component diagram shows static structure - so probably less relevant.

Comment: thx..but what i want to ask is, i want to draw a class diagram, it show class stucture, what relation does it have, and for more detail what it do, will be described in sequence diagram. thats what i want to do, but i'm new in EJB, and i've read some article, they use component diagram, they just write how the component interact with each other, they do not write/mention a single pojo, as if they do not have a single pojo at all in their stucture. but i have, and i wanna know how to describe the structure of their connection or relationship in class perspective and component perspective.. thx

Comment: will post as answer rather than comment, more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[per question in comment on how to draw class diagram]

Class diagrams are probably most often used for showing relationships in a problem domain.  The relationships capture rules from the domain (e.g. "Each order consists of one or more orderlines" / "each orderline forms part of exactly one order").

In your case the classes span the layers of the architecture.  Therefore the relationships capture architectural rules rather than domain rules.  I don't tend to use class diagrams for that purpose, but the principle is the same.  For each pair of classes you need to ask:

- How would you describe the relationship among the classes?
- What's the cardinality?

For example, take servlet & client.  How would you describe the relationship?  Probably something like:

- description: client *calls* servlet / servlet *is called by* client
- cardinality: for each given client instance, how many servlets can it talk to? Probably one or more.  Similarly, how many clients can a single servlet instance receive requests from?  Again probably one or more (will depend on your design)

Assuming above are correct for your design you'd have something like the following (apologies for the formatting, yuml.me doesn't seem to place text cleanly):

[image: client-server class diagram example]

Same approach applies for remaining classes.  First ask how you'd describe the relationship as a sentence, then figure out the cardinality.  For example, take the servlet-request handler: how would you describe that?  I'm not very familiar with java EE patterns, but would guess the servlet delegates to the request handler.  So relationship phrase would be something like "servlet *delegates request to* request handler".  And so on to ejb class, etc.

hth.

Comment: thx alot, i see your point.. i've edit the question, please see my image, is that right to draw like that? the servlet is component managed by web container, client request to the container, the container give the client the right servlet based on url sent by client. so the container that decide is there need to create another instance of servlet or not.. so i mark it by 1..* relation..

Comment: Apologies for delayed reply.  You're on the right lines, although 2 observations: (1) Use more meaningful terms than RequestHandler_X etc.  (Am assuming you will and diag is just for example).  (2) I really think you'd be better served with an activity/sequence diagram.  Most of your comments implicitly suggest you want to show "how it works".  Activity/Sequence diags are better for that.  Class diagrams show how it's structured, not how it works.  Best of luck whichever way you go though.